Powershell "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" though nothing is null
I ran the following powershell code for a few active directory accounts as a test.  I will have 30,000 accounts to manage.
   get-eduser ... | % {
      if ($_.mailNickName -eq $ADID) {
         # do nothing
      } else {
         try {
            Set-ADUser -Identity $DN -Replace @{mailNickName=$ADID}
            "mailNickName of {0} changed to {1}" -f $DN, $ADID >> $CHANGE_LOG
         } catch {
            $errmsg = (($error[0]).exception).Message
            "Writing to mailNickname failed for {0}: {1}" -f $emplid, $errmsg >> $ERROR_LOG
         }
      }
   }

and it returned the error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression".  I had taken care and verified that that none of the variables in the code block was null:

$DN was an existing active directory account,
$ADID was a valid string,
the mailNickName of %DN was not null and had a value that was different from $ADID,
$CHANGE_LOG and $ERROR_LOG were valid file paths

A few things are puzzling:

What did the "null-valued expression" refer to?  I can not think of
any variable that was null.
Despite the "null-valued expression" complaint, the first line of code in the try-block
actually did change the mailNickName value for the user account.
However, the next line of code following set-aduser did get bypassed since execution jumped to
the catch-block, therefore the mainNickName change did not get logged.
The "null-valued expression" error message did not get saved to the error log as expected, by
the code in the catch-block.  It was displayed on the screen only when the output redirection
to the error log was commented out ( # >> $ERROR_LOG).

The purpose of the script was to change the mailNickName value to $ADID if it was not already up-to-date, and get either the change or any error logged.  But the changes were not logged, I had no idea which accounts had been updated after the run.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help with my questions:

What did the "null-valued expression" in the error message refer to?
How to avoid such misleading error being triggered?
How to get the changes or errors logged?


It looks like you're swallowing some of the error context in your catch { ... } block. If you remove the entire try { } catch { } and just call the bare code from the try { ... } do you still get the error (and can you post the full error message from it)? Does it contain any additional information?

PowerShell does not make up errors, so if you're getting the exception, something is null. There is no misleading error. All the errors that occur actually exist, whether you can immediately find them or not.

Does it say which line and char the error occurred on?

See $Error[0].InvocationInfo

You said you did check the value of $DN but did you check the value of $_?

Curious enough,  there are no methods at all in your [mcve] (I recommend you to follow @mclayton's comment). One additional thing to mention though: $error[0] yields the last error, to retrieve the current (Try) error, use the current (error) object $_ in the Catch, meaning: $_.exception.message

What is get-eduser ? Did you mean Get-ADUser perhaps?

Thanks to all of you contributing ideas and sorry for my delayed response.  I tried all that you suggested.
The bottom line is, as Ken White pointed out, there must be something that is null.  But the null thing is quite unexpected. None of the variables in the command line was null.  However, when you -replace @{mailNickName=$ADID}, it involves the old value that is being replaced.  There were user accounts whose mailNickName were null, and that caused the "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" error.
Also a strange thing is that, despite the error it caught, Powershell nevertheless executed the Set-Aduser command and replaced the null with the new value provided.  That was not bad.  The problem was that once it issued the error, none of the commands in the try{} block following Set-Aduser got executed as execution jumped to the catch{} block.  The most important thing that could not afford to be skipped was the command line to write an entry to the change log about the changed mailNickName value for that user.
My solution is to have the change log entry saved in the catch{} block:
catch {
   $errmsg = $_.exception.message
   if ($errmsg -match "null-valued") {
      $nickname_after = (get-aduser -Identity $DN -Properties mailNickName).mailNickName
      if ($nickname_after -eq $cunyADID) {
         # writing to the change log
      }
   } else {
      ...
   }
}

I tried not using try{}catch{}, but that did not prevent the trigger of the "null-valued expression" error.
The $error[0].invocationinfo is quite useful.
And get-eduser was my typo.  It should be get-aduser.
Thank you all for helping!
